# Open Dropdown on click of Textview

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have a `TextView` named **Change City**. On click of **Change city** it has to show list of cities in dropdown list. Once the city is selected **Change City** has to be replaced by corresponding City name.

I tried using adapter (like `Spinner`) for `TextView`. It didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just use an actual `Spinner`? Adapters don't work with any view, they work with AdapterViews like Spinner or ListView.

Comment: You should post your code so that someone can help you.
You could have an onClickListener added to the `TextView`. That onClickListener could then fire the Spinner.

Comment: A Spinner is the correct way to do this. Post your code so we can see why the Spinner didn't work.

Comment: What you're describe is exactly the behaviour of a `Spinner`. Post the code you tried with a `Spiner` and somebody will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In a dropdown list I recently implemented, I used a `ListView` with an adapter set to an `ArrayList`. It worked great for me. I would recommend it.